# Concatenate multiple PostreSQL JSON columns in a single JSON root object

Tags: json, perl, postgresql, mojolicious

I have a table (*preferences*), with several JSON columns (*design_prefs*, *country_prefs*, *view_prefs*, *payment_prefs*, etc.)

*design_prefs* --> `{"color":"red", "height":15}`

*country_prefs* --> `{"language":"en", "currency":"pound"}`

*view_prefs* --> `{"layout":"list", "sortby":"category1", "view_brand":1, "view_price":1}`

etc.

I retrieve a single row, but only with the columns required by the web context. Maybe just *design_prefs*, or *design_prefs* AND *country_prefs*, or *design_prefs* AND *payment_prefs* or whatever combination.

In the application (using Perl, Mojolicious and Mojo::Pg) I convert each JSON column in a Hash (key/value dictionary object used in Perl). And then I concatenate the multiple resulting hashes in a big "preferences" hash object.

It is working, but I would like to do the concatenation in Postgres, so in Mojolicious I only need to do a "JSON to hash" process.

Looking for aggregation functions in Postgresql I have found ways to do something like this:

```
{"color":"red", "height":15 }, {"language":"en", "currency":"pound"}
```

But I need this:

```
{"color":"red", "height":15, "language":"en", "currency":"pound"}
```

JSON type is stored as text in Pg 9.3, including the initial and ending bracket characters, so direct text concatenation is not a way.

Any guidance is appreciated, even recommendation to forget the idea and keep using the application instead the database.

Comment: Perhaps `json_merge` https://gist.github.com/matheusoliveira/9488951

Comment: Not a json expert, but what if you trim brackets and then concatenate?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no clean way to achieve this in posgres 9.3. In 9.4, there is `json_object_agg` that might do the job

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something more 'native' than pure text manipulation. In such a simple search and replace of brackets and commas I am not sure about a big improvement when done in the server.